# How to setup GKE cluster with committed use VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am looking to purchase committed use VMs for my application. However, with my limited knowledge, I am unsure about following

- After purchasing committed use VMs and then create a GKE cluster, will the new cluster automatically use the newly purchased VMs and I will be charged accordingly? OR
- If the new cluster doesn't detect committed use VM's how do I assign the VMs to the new cluster?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 2 types of commitments

1. if you use CPU and Memory commitment, it's easy. You commit a number of CPU and a volume of memory, and you will pay for it, in the selected region, for 1 or 3 years. if your cluster use CPU and Memory in this same region, the committed CPU and Memory are automatically detected and thus not billed (you pay only the CUD). If you use more, you will pay-as-you-use only the amount above the CUD. if you use less, you will pay the CUD only.
2. If you want to commit GPU and SSD, it's more difficult because you need to define a reservation. Firstly it's per zone, and not per region, that increase the difficulty. In addition, a reservation define a machine profile (Number of CPU, Volume of Memory, Number of GPU, Number of local SSD). To use this CUD in your cluster, your node must match EXACTLY the VM profile that you defined. If, after 1 year, you want to increase the CPU or the memory of your node, the VM profile won't match the CUD reservation and it won't work (you will pay twice: 1 for the unused reservation, 1 for the node).